# Need Electron App to be launched from http uri scheme

Tags: javascript, http, electron

I am developing a simple Electron app that displays images from a server.  Using app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient, I made it so that the .exe is run when a user enters the uri scheme "iv://", and the parameters are passed to the program and used.

This application will be called from another program which opens generated links on button presses.  At present, it is directed at a server which hosts the current web application which I am replacing.  Its URL looks something like this: http://10.10.20.3?id=123456&name=example.

Before deploying my new application on a wide scale, we're going to be testing it out on a few devices.  To do this, I am required to have it so that said generated URL's trigger my Electron Application.  In other words, that URL (http uri scheme and all) has to open my desktop app and pass the parameters to it.  I'm not allowed to change anything on the side of the current program.

I'm assuming that setting my Electron App as the default web browser can effectively get the desired result, but I don't know how to do that.  Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know your application but just be aware setting your Electron App as the default browsers will put the user at risk if they are using your app to browse the open web. Browsers are updated every 3 to 6 week to fix vulnerabilities. Electron is not.

Comment: @gman It's only for temporary, one-time testing purposes, definitely will not be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're requesting is called [Deep Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking). As for electron, you can check the example in  [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol).

```
  const {app, protocol} = require('electron')
  const path = require('path')

  app.on('ready', () => {
    protocol.registerFileProtocol('atom', (request, callback) => {
      const url = request.url.substr(7)
      callback({path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`)})
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
    })
  })
```